# Увеличение шрифта на 6 пунктов с каждой новой строчкой

Tags: javascript, шрифты

Дана задача: Запросить у пользователя число от 1 до 10. Вывести его на страницу прописью 10 раз в столбик, увеличивая размер шрифта на 6 пунктов.
Вот pastebin как я пытался её решить. https://pastebin.com/2gZrBLmX.
Помогите пожалуйста!

```js
num = prompt('Enter number from 1 to 10')
if ((num > 10) || (num < 1)) {
  alert('Error. Type number from 1 to 10')
} else {
  for (var q = 1; q <= 10; q++) {
    document.write("<div id='res" + q + "' onclick='clck(" + q + ")' ></div>" + num)
    for (var y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {
      document.getElementById('res' + y).style.fontSize = fontSize + "50px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="res">
</div>
```

Comment: Скопируйте сюда код.

Answer (score 3):

Вообщем-то у вас хороший код, только в этой строчке вам нужно додумать логику

```
document.getElementById( 'res' + y).style.fontSize = fontSize + "50px";
```

Вам нужно завести переменную на размер шрифта, в каждой итерации цикла её увеличивать, и потом делать `fontSize+"px"`.

Кроме того возможно ваши два цикла объединить в один. Для этого, например можно задавать стили inline, например `<div style="font-size:40px"></div>`.

Comment: А какой размер шрифта в HTML по умолчанию?

Comment: @Dmtr зависит от браузера, но обычно делают 14, если не вдаваться во все возможные ситуации

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что при загрузке страницы style считается пустым. Я не знаю как исправить.

Comment: @Dmtr Вы можете сами задать начальное значение размера вашего шрифта, вам не надо брать его откуда-то.

Answer (score 2):

Размер шрифта можно получить с помощью [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Ну а далее я бы сделал так :

```js
var num = prompt('Enter number from 1 to 10');
var size = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

if (num > 10 || num < 1) {
  alert('Error. Type number from 1 to 10');
} else {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = num;
    div.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    document.body.append(div);
    size += 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую. JS для решения данной задачи не нужен. CSS (SCSS) достаточно. Если по какой-то причине препроцессор не используется (не верю), тогда можно воспользоваться переменными css или, в крайнем случае, скопировать выход после sass-а:

```
.preview {
  @for $i from 1 through 10 {
    > div:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      font-size: 1px * $i * 6;
    }
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/rasdaniil/pen/KZNgyP

Comment: Также в 2017-м году не стоит использовать юнит 'px'. rem и em для шрифтов куда лучше (предсказуемее), так как экраны девайсов теперь очень разные (сравните 1024х768 vs 5k).

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych  согласен

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, у меня не работает с window.getComputedStyle, хоть и на сайте всё показывает...

```js
var num = prompt('Enter number from 1 to 10');
var size = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

if (num > 10 || num < 1) {
  alert('Error. Type number from 1 to 10');
} else {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = num;
    div.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    document.body.append(div);
    size += 5;
  }
}
```